# Having issues changing a string in my react component on a state update

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, axios, components

I have a string that represents my file name which I will be passing to the react-csv CSVLink<> component. I initially define the string as something like "my-data.csv", and am trying to update it with the appropriate data I receive from an axios request. It seems I don't understand the true flow of how these react components work and when data is available. I have the following at the top of my file before the component is rendered.

```
let fileName = "my-data.csv";
...
const setFileName = (tabName?) => {
    if (!data || !data?.moreData) { // I thought this would be a way to check if the data has been retrieved yet
      return "equipment-data.csv";
    }
    return tabname != "Average Data"
      ? "Equipment " + tabname + " " + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv" // format it with data name + date
      : tabname + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv"; // Same as above, this just results in a different file name
  };
```

Further along in my component where it is actually rendered/returned, I try to set it like so:

```
<CSVLink fileName={setFileName()} data={testData} />
```

However, this isn't grabbing all the data to format the file correctly. It returns something like "Equipment undefined 01-18-2021.csv", so it's not grabbing everything.

Initially, I simply tried updating the "filename" string within the setFileName() function itself. Something like this:

```
const setFileName = (tabName?) => {
    if (!data || !data?.moreData) { // I thought this would be a way to check if the data has been retrieved yet
      fileName = "equipment-data.csv";
    }
    return tabname != "Average Data"
      ? fileName = "Equipment " + tabname + " " + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv" // format it with data name + date
      : fileName = tabname + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv"; // Same as above, this just results in a different file name
  };
```

But this resulted in the file name never actually being changed, but rather stuck with the placeholder value I give it in the first place. Any answers and explanations as to why this isn't working would be a lifesaver :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `TabName` is wrong case in the return statement. How about change `tabname` to `tabName`?

I guess it should be like this.

```js
const setFileName = (tabName?) => {
    if (!data || !data?.moreData) { // I thought this would be a way to check if the data has been retrieved yet
      fileName = "equipment-data.csv";
    }
    return tabName != "Average Data"
      ? fileName = "Equipment " + tabName + " " + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv" // format it with data name + date
      : fileName = tabName + `${data.dates[0].date}` + ".csv"; // Same as above, this just results in a different file name
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed a lot of variable names because it was company-specific code, so that was just a result of me improperly naming it when I copied stuff over to here. It's correct in the actual code (with a different name)